# Convert datetime from PDT to UTC in python

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I have an object of <class 'datetime.datetime'>.

```
obj = datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 28, 2, 15, tzinfo=<FixedOffset '-07:00'>)
```

The time zone is PDT(offset -7:00). I need to convert it to UTC.

So if the object has datetime as `2021-05-02 10:00:00.000 -07:00`.
It should be changed to `2021-05-02 17:00:00.000 +00:00`.

How to achieve this in python?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, using [`.astimezone()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> obj = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> obj
datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 19, 13, 18, 26, 601212)
>>> obj.astimezone(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 19, 17, 18, 26, 601212, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Comment: For UTC, you'll want `astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc)`

Answer (score -3):

use time delta

```
bj = dt.datetime(2021,6,28,10,0)+dt.timedelta(hours=7)
pd.to_datetime(bj)
```